# Set default value for column programmatically

Tags: postgresql

I need help to exchange the default value of column in postgres according to the value of other column.

I mean: if column B has value 1, the default value of column A has to be seq_one. If column B has value 2, the default value of column A has to be seq_two.

Comment: That sounds broken. Why does it matter what sequence is being used?

Comment: This can be accomplished with a trigger, not plain DDL, but @AdrianKlaver is likely correct. This is a database schema code smell.

Comment: It's not broken. I just have to adapt some preview work made by other person

Comment: Then tell them the preview work is broken.